# Image button picture change

Tags: vba, powerpoint, imagebutton

If a user activates an image button the button's picture should change. I use this code.

```
Dim mainslide As Object
Set mainslide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

If mainslide.Shapes(11).Name = "green" Then
    mainslide.Shapes(11).Picture = LoadPicture("pathname")
    fődia.Shapes(11).Name = "red"
Else
    mainslide.Shapes(11).Picture = LoadPicture("pathname2")
    fődia.Shapes(11).Name = "green"
End If
```

I get runtime error 438, but in Excel this method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fodia isn't defined in your example, so it's difficult to guess what it should be.  But I don't think that's the source of the problem.  Here's another approach that works.  A couple of points to note:

PPT's handling of ActiveX objects is strange.  To get to the properties you're used to for control objects, you have to use Shape.OLEFormat.Object.property_name

And in at least some versions, ActiveX shapes don't appear in the normal shape order; you can tab through the shapes on the slide to select each in turn, but the ActiveX shape is never selected.  Naming the shape is one workaround (and one that won't change when the shapes are reordered, so it's a bit more reliable).

```
Sub RedOrGreen()

Dim mainslide As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Set mainslide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oSh = FindShapeNamed("green", mainslide)
If Not oSh Is Nothing Then
    oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\temp\red.jpg")
    oSh.Name = "red"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set oSh = FindShapeNamed("red", mainslide)
If Not oSh Is Nothing Then
    oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\temp\green.jpg")
    oSh.Name = "green"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Function FindShapeNamed(sName As String, oSl As Slide) As Shape
    Dim oSh As Shape
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.Name = sName Then
            Set FindShapeNamed = oSh
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: fodia is the mainslide i've forgot to translate it. :(
Thanks for the answer